# Enterprise edition Scratch Org with Customer Community Licenses

Tags: salesforcedx, customer-community, lightning-community, salesforcedx-cli, scratch-org

Looking to understand whether it is possible to get Customer Community licenses in an Enterprise Edition Scratch Org. Scratch Org definition I tried to use for this was the following:

**Scratch Org Definition - Enterprise Edition**

```json
{
  "orgName": "Test Company",
  "edition": "Enterprise",
  "features": ["Communities", "ForceComPlatform"],
  "settings": {
    "orgPreferenceSettings": {
      "networksEnabled": true,
      "s1DesktopEnabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

**Workaround - Set it as Developer Edition**

The workaround to get the Customer Community licensing was to set the Scratch Org edition as Developer (see below).

```json
{
  "orgName": "Test Company",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": ["Communities", "ForceComPlatform"],
  "settings": {
    "orgPreferenceSettings": {
      "networksEnabled": true,
      "s1DesktopEnabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

This isn't ideal as it doesn't truly reflect the edition I'll be deploying too. There are also some things missing such as [Setting Up the Community Cloud Content Delivery Network](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_cdn.htm&type=5) and [Usage Allocation Differentials](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_usage_allocation.htm&type=5).

Just looking to find out if it is actually possible to create an Enterprise Edition with Customer Community Licensing?